# how to redraw the zsh prompt after widget action

Tags: command-prompt, zsh, cd

Using zsh, i would like to add a shortcut to go in parent directory.
Easy peasy to do that

```
cdup() {
  builtin cd ..
}
zle -N cdup
bindkey "your_favorite_key_code" cdup
```

But this does not redraw the prompt, anybody knows how to do it?

Binding shortcuts to do pushd/popd could be an idea too, to be honest i got those ideas from the "fish shell".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've recently implemented the exact same thing. The best solution I can come up with is the following

```
cdup() {
  cd ..
  zle reset-prompt
}
```

The `zle reset-prompt` is the bit that gets it to redraw the prompt.

**Edit**:
My previous version of the answer had a `printf '\n'` in the answer. This was necessary if the prompt was a multi-line prompt. However zsh apparently has tons of issues with mutli-lines prompts, so I dropped it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it even keeps what is currently written on the prompt line! The `printf '\n'` is welcome because when i change of directory i have the new pwd printed.