# How to refresh terminal after function call

Tags: terminal, zsh, ls, oh-my-zsh, cd

I've written a simple function to search the current folder when I press ctrl+f with exa and peco, after I choose a directory I want to cd into it.

(ll is modified version of ls)

```
pecofunc() {
  ll | peco --layout=bottom-up | read foo 
  foo="${foo##* }"
  if [ -n "$foo" ] 
  then
    builtin cd "$foo"
  fi
  # refresh terminal and end execution
}
zle -N pecofunc pecofunc
bindkey '^f' pecofunc
```

This part works well but after executing it my directory doesn't visually change until I press enter or use other command.

Picture 1
[Terminal before doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7mbP.png)

Picture 2 [After pressing ctrl+f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDpyd.png)

Picture 3 [Choosing test2 and pressing enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXAI.png)

Picture 4 [Pressing enter again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh3Is.png)

Pressing enter again refreshes the folder which I'm in but creates another newline which is unacceptable.

How can I avoid this issue?

This is a [crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1700881/how-to-refresh-terminal-after-function-call) from superuser.com, there are already some answers on that side which did not work.

Comment: See [how to redraw the zsh prompt after widget action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212508/how-to-redraw-the-zsh-prompt-after-widget-action)

Comment: @rowboat nice suggestion but doesn't. Behavior does not change at all! :/